# Why is my custom UIActivity no longer visible in a UIActivityViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uiactivityviewcontroller, uiactivity

I have created a custom `UIActivity` and it was working, and I presented that `UIActivityController` as per typical tutorials (e.g. [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/118/uiactivityviewcontroller-by-example)).  When configuring that controller I disabled basically all the services:

```
    let items = [location]
    
    let googlemaps = GoogleMapsActivity()
    let applemaps = AppleMapsActivity()
    
    let ac = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: items, applicationActivities: [googlemaps, applemaps])
    ac.excludedActivityTypes = [.addToReadingList, .assignToContact, .markupAsPDF, .openInIBooks, .postToFacebook, .postToFlickr, .postToVimeo, .postToWeibo, .postToTwitter, .postToTencentWeibo, .print, .saveToCameraRoll]
    present(ac, animated: true)
```

Then I might have stumbled onto an iOS Bug?

When that activity view controller was visible I tapped on "More", which gave me a list of my 2 custom activities.  There was no `UISwitch` to turn them on an off, but there was a typical "row handle" as in a `UITableView`.  I was testing, and tried re-arranging rows.  This made one of the activities disappear from that list and now that activity is gone forever.

It won't appear in a list again, even if I delete and re-install the app.  It seems I permanently removed the ability for this iOS device to make use of that `UIActivity`.

What have I done wrong or how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It might have had something to do with these 2 custom activities ultimately sharing the same UIActivity.ActivityType rawValue.  I refactored that so they have different values and the issue doesn't seem to occur anymore, or I haven't been able to reproduce it.